# In Django, why does request.get_full_path not allow me to redirect to a dynamic url using href?

Tags: django

I'm struggling to understand why this piece of code doesn't allow me to redirect to another page from an html template using the href parameter. I'm trying to use the current full path of the page, because it's filled with dynamic url values, to create an additional add-on to the url to create a form. For some reason however, when I click on the link on the page, the url changes in the address bar, but the page doesn't redirect or go to the page.

```
<a href = "{{ request.get_full_path }}/newstory">Create New Story</a>
```

Any help will be gladly appreciated!

Comment: Do you pass `request` to template in view?

Comment: does `request.get_full_path` resolve to the right URL ? Also, are you using jquery mobile ?

Comment: Yes, I did pass request to template in view. Request.get_full_path does resolve to the right URL, but it doesn't redirect me when I press the link. Only the link in the address bar changes. Finally, I'm not using jquery mobile.

Comment: Maybe you should remove the  slash